# Excel summing values based on value of different column in same row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm sure this has probably been answered before or is somewhere through a google search, but I don't know how to word it properly to find that result.

So, I have some data in one sheet, in the following format, bearing in mind that this data has no vertical limit, so there can be any number of rows.

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHLwq.png)

My question is, what formula do I need to put into the '[some value]' cell to get the sum of all 'points' values with a given ID.

[destination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYK4X.png)

Essentially I want the equivalent of a SQL "Select...Where..." query

Comment: What you're looking for is named SUMIF, google it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula in B2 in the Destination sheet:
`=SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A,A2,Sheet1!D:D)`

Sheet1 is where you have Data (column A for ID, column D where you have points)
column A should have Data Rows as Column D
A2 is the Id in destination sheet which you want to sum the points
and you can drag the formula down

Answer (score 1):

SUMIF will resolve your problem.
https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumif.php